# Bootstrap form validation not validating before submit (not showing the errors)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I try to validate my contact form with Bootstrap 4, it validates it well just after submit, but if I fill the wrong info in a field and change to another field nothing happens, I want it to highlight the errors before submitting the form.

here is a [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/gabonessi/pen/axvjVr)

This is my form :

```
<form id="contact-form" class="needs-validation" action="contact/send" method="POST" novalidate>
     <div class="form-group">
       <label for="#contactName">Nombre y Apellido*:</label>
       <input id="contactName" class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Escribe..." required>
       <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        Introduzca su nombre completo
       </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="#email">Correo Electronico*:</label>
          <input id="email" class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="tucorreo@mail.com" required>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Introduzca su correo electronico
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="#phone">Telefono*:</label>
          <input id="phone" class="form-control" type="tel" name="phone" minlength="11" maxlength="11" placeholder="04141112233" required>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
             Introduzca su número de teléfono
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="course-select">Curso que le interesa*:</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="selectCourse" id="course-select">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="panaderia basica">Panadería Básica</option>
            <option value="pan de jamon">Pan de Jamón, cachitos y trencitas de queso</option>
            <option value="masa brioche">Masa Brioche</option>
            <option value="golfeados y quesadillas">Golfeados y quesadillas</option>
            <option value="trenza de chocolate y rosca de navidad">Trenza de Chocolate y Rosca de Navidad</option>
            <option value="hojaldre">Hojaldre</option>
            <option value="pan Campesino y focaccia">Pan Campesino y Focaccia</option>
            <option value="panes de fibra">Panes de Fibra</option>
            <option value="ninguno">Otro</option>
          </select>
       </div>

       <div class="form-group">
         <label for="message">Tu mensaje*:</label>
         <textarea name="message" class="form-control" id="message" cols="40" rows="2" minlength="50" maxlength="300" placeholder="Escribe al menos 50 caracteres..." required></textarea>
         <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Su mensaje debe tener minimo 50 caracteres.
         </div>
        </div>

        <input class="form-button" type="submit" value="Enviar">
          <p>* Campos obligatorios</p>
        </form>
```

this is my jQuery:

```
formValidation();

function formValidation(){
    var $form = $('.needs-validation');

    $form.on('submit', function(e) {
        if (this.checkValidity() === false) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
        $form.addClass('was-validated');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> but if I fill the wrong info in a field and change to another field nothing happens.

So you may need to watch the `blur` action, add another event for this :

```
formValidation();

function formValidation() {
  var $form = $('.needs-validation');

  $form.on('submit', function(e) {
    validate(e, $form);
  });
  $form.find('input, select, textarea').on('blur', function(e) {
    validate(e, $(this));
  });
}

function validate(e, elem) {
  if (elem[0].checkValidity() === false) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
  elem.addClass('was-validated');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, the code is not working, it no longers validates even when submit.

Comment: nope, still not validating even when sending an empty form

Comment: haha, it does work but not exactly as expected, when you fill up the first field and click into another field then all the fields of the form are showing the errors, I want the errors to appear individually on each field as you complete. We getting closer!

Comment: Nope, only validates when submitted. :(

Answer (score 0):

In line with Zakaria's answer I would also suggest adding onKeyup event too

```js
$form.find('input').on('keyup', function(e) {
  validate($form);
});
```

This would run the validation as and when you type